# How convert qualitativ data in quantitative data

Tags: python, pandas, lasso-regression

I have this result :

```
      YEARMADERANGE  NCOMBATH  TOTROOMS  NUMFRIG  NUMFREEZ  STOVEN  OVEN  \
0                 7         2         7        1         1       1     0   
1                 5         1         4        1         1       1     0   
2                 4         2         9        2         0       2     0   
3                 2         2         7        2         1       1     0   
4                 4         2         6        2         0       1     1   
...             ...       ...       ...      ...       ...     ...   ...   
5681              3         1         3        1         0       1     0   
5682              1         1         5        1         1       1     0   
5683              7         1         3        1         1       1     0   
5684              7         2         5        2         0       1     1   
5685              4         1         3        1         0       1     0   

      MICRO  FOODPROC  DISHWASH  DRYER  TVCOLOR  DESKTOP  HEATHOME  SWAMPCOL  \
0         1         0         1      1        2        0         1         0   
1         1         0         0      0        2        0         1         0   
2         2         0         1      1        4        1         1         0   
3         1         0         0      1        5        1         1        -2   
4         1         0         0      1        5        0         1        -2   
...     ...       ...       ...    ...      ...      ...       ...       ...   
5681      1         0         0      0        2        0         1        -2   
5682      1         1         0      1        1        0         1         0   
5683      1         0         0      0        2        0         1        -2   
5684      1         0         1      1        2        1         1         0   
5685      1         0         1      0        2        0         1        -2   

      SMARTMETER  NHSLDMEM  NOHEATDAYS  USEEL  
0              1         4          -2      1  
1              1         2          -2      1  
2             -9         4          -2      1  
3              0         1          -2      1  
4              0         3          -2      1  
...          ...       ...         ...    ...  
5681          -9         1          -2      1  
5682          -9         2          -2      1  
5683           0         1          -2      1  
5684          -9         2          -2      1  
5685           0         1          -2      1
```

But my columns "NOHEATDAYS" is composed of Qualitativ data and I want to transform this in Quantitativ/numeriacl data for do my regression Lasso. How I can do that ?

Thanks you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please write a [mcve]. Explicit what is your input made of and what is the expected result

Answer (score 0):

By "Qualitativ" do you mean it is a string? If so you can apply a function to the column like this:

```
new_df = df.apply(lambda x: int(x) if x.name == 'NOHEATDAYS' else x)
```